# Hide menu items from non-authenticated user

Tags: routes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hiding link from anonymous users](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32718/hiding-link-from-anonymous-users)

I have 2 nodes on Drupal 7 site, that only authenticated users can access. But even if I logout, links to these nodes appear in the main menu. When I click any of them, it gives:

```
Access denied 
You are not authorized to access this page.
```

Which is correct. As far as I know, Drupal must hide the links, that the user can't access. But for these items it doesn't.

How to fix?

[image]

Comment: Please check if answers for this [question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32718/hiding-link-from-anonymous-users) helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely a bug in Drupal core. It shouldn't give links, the user doesn't have access to.

I fixed it, using the programming in page.tpl.php in my theme, adding if($user->uid != 0):

```
<?php
      global $user;
      if($user->uid != 0)
      {
             if ($main_menu):
?>
      <div id="main-menu" class="navigation">
        <?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
          'links' => $main_menu,
          'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'main-menu-links',
            'class' => array('links', 'clearfix'),
          ),
          'heading' => array(
            'text' => t('Main menu'),
            'level' => 'h2',
            'class' => array('element-invisible'),
          ),
        )); ?>
      </div> <!-- /#main-menu -->
    <?php
               endif;
      }
 ?>
```

Comment: Its not a bug actually. It depends on the scenario/requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Follow Below things:

1) Make sure that in admin/people/permissions "View published content", "view own Unpublished Content are "Unchecked" for the "anonymous user".

2)  Still if you are getting those "Disclaimer and Policies" menu links. 
   i) Create a  new menu and add those links in to that menu. While adding links Give the Parent menu link to "Main Menu". and save the menu.
   ii) Then admin/structure/block, configure the menu block: Give the permission to access only to Authenticated User  and save the block